# How to convert a JSON string to arrays in Javacript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I need a simple help with this question, I'm trying to convert a JSON string to two arrays, look the example:

```
// What I have
var str = '{"id":1,"name":"Test1"},{"id":2,"name":"Test2"}'; 


// What I need:
var array1 = {"id":1,"name":"Test1"};
var array2 = {"id":2,"name":"Test2"};
```

I tried to do it using `JSON.parse(str)`, but with no success like below:

```js
//Works:

var str = '{"id":1,"name":"Test1"}';
dataObj = JSON.parse(str);
console.log(dataObj)

//Doesn't work:

var str = '{"id":1,"name":"Test1"},{"id":2,"name":"Test2"}';
dataObj = JSON.parse(str);
console.log(dataObj)
```

Any suggestion ?

Comment: That string isn't valid JSON. Also your two "arrays" aren't arrays, they are objects. You probably want to fix the source of your JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all you want to do is put the objects in array

```
var str = '[{"id":1,"name":"Test1"},{"id":2,"name":"Test2"}]';
dataObj = JSON.parse(str);
console.log(dataObj)
```

then:

```
var array1 = dataObj[0];
var array2 = dataObj[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't properly formatted your JSON string.

It should have been `var str = '[{"id":1,"name":"Test1"},{"id":2,"name":"Test2"}]';`

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that '{"id":1,"name":"Test1"},{"id":2,"name":"Test2"}' isn't valid JSON format.

Try this:

```
var str = '[{"id":1,"name":"Test1"},{"id":2,"name":"Test2"}]';
dataObj = JSON.parse(str);
console.log(dataObj)
```

If you want assign objects to two separated variables (as you described):

```
var obj1 = dataObj[0];
var obj2 = dataObj[1];
```

I renamed variable names because what is assigned to variable is object, not an array